# Remove height property using @media

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

```css
p {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 150px;
}

@media screen and(min-width: 700 px) {
  p {
    max-height: 150 px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
   Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
   Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello 
   Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello 
</p>

<strong>h1</strong>
```

I want to remove the `height` property when screen width is less than 700px. If I do `height:0px;`, it completely hides the paragraph.  Any CSS solution? Or do I need to use jQuery?

Comment: Your code has a bunch of errors. You have spaces in the wrong place like between 150 and px. Use a syntax highlighter

Comment: That does not matter @Ihazkode

Comment: CSS doesn't read `150 px` it only reads `150px`. Same for  `overflow - y: hidden;` which your code had prior to the edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `height: auto` in the media query. That's the default setting. It will overwrite the fixed height in your standard CSS.

```css
p {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  p {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
</p>

<strong>h1</strong>
```

BTW: You have to write `@media screen and (min-width: 700px)` -> no space between "700" and "px", no space between "150" and "px" for `min-height`, but a space between "and" and the opening "(" in the media query

Answer (score 3):

You can add, for smaller screens, media query height:auto

```
@media screen and(max-width: 700 px) {
  p {
    height:auto
  }
}
```

or create height only in larger screens.

```
p {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
@media screen and(min-width: 700 px) {
  p {
    height:150px
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`height: auto` will do the work since it will "reset" it to the default height so you dont have to worry about the run time height.

> #### `auto`
>
> The browser will calculate and select a height for the specified element.

If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, and the element is not absolutely positioned, the value of its height computes to **auto**(it will be as tall as the content inside it is, or zero if there is no content)

Answer (score 0):

try `height: auto;` inside media query where `max-width` is `699`

and then put that `height: 150px;` inside another media query above the range of that width, `min-width` is `700`

Comment: why @CodeWizard

Comment: Since it will override any other css definition and it will hard to maintain, you will have hard time figure out why is it 0. if someone else has to maintain your code he will have hard time

Comment: @CodeWizard well, infact yes, but the OP have a generric style, that have to be overriden, I have edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

When you don't use `height` property, CSS will use default value of `height`. So you can set `height` property to default value `auto`.